# How to get output of sklearn.metrics.classification_report as a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I have been trying to get the classification report in the form of a dictionary.
So according to the scikit-learn 0.20 documentation, I do:

```
from sklearn import metrics

rep = metrics.classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
```

But get an error saying

```
TypeError: classification_report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_dict'
The scikit-learn module in my machine was initially 0.19.1 but even after updating it to 0.20, the same error message shows.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error should not show up as long as you have scikit-learn 0.20.0 installed. If you are trying this in a jupyter notebook, make sure the correct version reflects in your notebook using:

```
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
```

If you've upgraded scikit-learn but jupyter shows the wrong version of the package, make sure jupyter is installed in your current environment (and restart jupyter in a new terminal).