# TypeError: classification_report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_dict'

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I have some code that is applying the random forest algorithm in order to predict the value of the gold column based on the remaining columns.

My input file is under the form:

```
gold,MethodType,CallersT,CallersN,CallersU,CallersCallersT,CallersCallersN,CallersCallersU,CalleesT,CalleesN,CalleesU,CalleesCalleesT,CalleesCalleesN,CalleesCalleesU,classGold,VariableTraceValue  
T,Inner,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,Trace,U
T,Inner,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,Trace,T
T,Inner,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,Trace,T
N,Inner,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,Trace,T
N,Inner,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,NoTrace,N
N,Leaf,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,U
N,Leaf,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,N
N,Inner,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,Inner,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,Leaf,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,U
N,Leaf,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,U
N,Leaf,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,N
N,Leaf,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,N
N,Leaf,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,N
N,Root,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,NoTrace,N
N,Leaf,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,NoTrace,U
N,Root,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,Inner,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,NoTrace,N
N,Inner,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,NoTrace,N
N,Root,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,NoTrace,U
```

I am trying to predict the value of the gold column which can take 2 values: T or N. I am printing the classification report of the random forest algorithm as shown below:
[image]

I want to store the T precision, N precision, T recall, and N recall into 4 separate variables. I am trying to use `output_dict` to do so but I receive the error message `classification_report() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output_dict'`.

Here is my source code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix, accuracy_score
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt




def main():
    
    X_train={}
    X_test={}
    y_train={}
    y_test={}
    
    path = 'NtoT'
    files = os.listdir(path)

    #for f in files:
    #print(f)
    filename=path+'\\'+'NtoT-2.5-9.txt'
    print(filename)
    dataset = pd.read_csv( filename, sep= ',', index_col=False) 

        #convert Inner, Root, Leaf into 0, 1, 2
       
    dataset['MethodType'] = dataset['MethodType'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['classGold'] = dataset['classGold'].astype('category').cat.codes
    dataset['VariableTraceValue'] = dataset['VariableTraceValue'].astype('category').cat.codes
        
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    
    row_count, column_count = dataset.shape
     
        
    X = dataset.iloc[:, 1:column_count].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
        
    
        
        
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=1)    
    
         
    ################################################################################
       
        
        
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=400, random_state=0)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)   
    
    report = classification_report(y_test,y_pred,output_dict=True)
    print('confusion matrix\n',confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))
    print('classification report\n', report)
    print('accuracy score', accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))     

   

if __name__=="__main__": 
    
        main()
```

How can I fix this and store the T precision, N precision, T recall, N recall into 4 separate variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you may have an outdated version of sklearn. Here you can find a explanation how to check your version:

[How to get output of sklearn.metrics.classification_report as a dict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740089/how-to-get-output-of-sklearn-metrics-classification-report-as-a-dict#52898079)